# Javascript error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, html

im having trouble with this code. it says i am missing a closing parentheses but it seems all of them are closed.here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(funtion(){
  $("#slide-toggle").click(funtion(){
    alert("Hello");
  });
});
```

Comment: Provided code is fine.. Issue is with the other part of the code which is not shared...

Comment: typo - `function` - should be `$("#slide-toggle").click(function(){`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney – You got a good eyesight ;)

Comment: typo also for the 'function' writen just upstair  `ready(function(){`

Comment: It's worth understanding why this slightly unhelpful syntax error is reported. Take the example `console.log(funtion() { });`. JS interprets `funtion` as a function to be invoked, with the result being passed to `console.log` as a parameter. However, after one parameter, we would expect a comma followed by additional parameters, or a closing parenthesis `)`. It is the latter that JS is reporting as being missing--since it found a `{` instead.

Comment: This is not a question to be answered. It's a simple typo and should be voted for closure instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

funtion() ==> function()

Change :

```
 $(document).ready(funtion(){


$("#slide-toggle").click(funtion(){
```

To :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#slide-toggle").click(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

USe function not funtion

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slide-toggle").click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see the reason for the down vote here

Comment: Answer is correct . but somehow downvoted